# String.endsWith(/[string]/[1-999]/)

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to parse the end of a url and redirect depending on it's ending.

For example, if I'm going to `www.something.com/foo/1/` I want to redirect to `www.something.com/foo/1/bar`. The 1 in this case can be any positive integer.

What I've been trying with but can't get to work is:

`if (window.location.href.endsWith('/foo/\d/')) {
    fetch stuff and redirect
}
else {
   do something else
}`

Which doesn't work, I'm guessing `endsWith` can't parse regex.

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Well that is not a regular expression, that is a string. Regular expressions do not sit inside of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code [`endsWith('/foo/\d/')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) check the string is ending with that particular string argument and won't work as a regex.

For checking using regex use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method with regex [`/foo\/\d{1,3}\/$/`](https://regex101.com/r/64nsE1/2).

```
if(/foo\/\d{1,3}\/$/.test(window.location.href))
```

Comment: @PeterHolmberg : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can regex match for the end of string instead,

```
/.*foo\d/$/
```

My regex might be wrong, but you can use the $ to denote end of string and just do a regular regex.test